# C# : line = StreamReader.ReadLine <= item

Tags: c#, string

Working with reading a file that's formatted like this

```
2014/11/03 14:31:03     PID:8696        UUID:2ae855da-37d1-4a99-8510-27539afa09d0       Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/SIPEngine_2.ininlog
2014/11/04 00:00:01     PID:8696        UUID:2ae855da-37d1-4a99-8510-27539afa09d0       End     E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/SIPEngine_2.ininlog
```

I am already stripping out the time in a variable but need to get be able to search the file for anything that is less than or equal to the value

Thanks to @dbc

Now I need to get the match on date

```
while (reader.next(msg, control))
{
  ActiveAttributesVect_t attribs = msg.get_active_context_attributes();
  ActiveAttributeValuesVect_t attribVals = msg.get_active_context_attribute_values();
  int numAttribs = ((attribs != null) && (attribVals != null)) ? Math.Min(attribs.Count, attribVals.Count) : 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < numAttribs; ++i)
  {
    if (attribVals[i].ToString().Contains(strCallID))
    {
      callidList.Add(msg.expand_format_message());
      // Setting the date to match the log format
      strCallDate = msg.timestamp().as_creator_time(header.tz_offset()).ToString().Substring(0, 10).Replace("-", "/");
      strCallTime = msg.timestamp().as_creator_time(header.tz_offset()).ToString().Substring(11, 8);



                    Console.WriteLine("Call Time : {0}", strCallTime);
                    Console.WriteLine("Call Date : {0}", strCallDate);
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    foreach (var entry in callidList)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(entry);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("");


                    OutputLogLinesBeforeTime(strLogDirectory, msg.timestamp().as_creator_time(header.tz_offset()), strCallTime);

                }
            }
```

Comment: Side note: You're not closing your files, as far as I can see. You don't even need a StreamReader, look at `System.IO.File.ReadLines(string fileName)`.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Use [`DateTime.Parse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the stripped-out time then simply use the [comparison operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff986512%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for `DateTime`.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I agree... or if it's a big file and you want to process it one line at a time you should wrap your FileStream and StreamReader in using statements.

Comment: @Kevin - re 'big file', check out ReadLines() vs ReadAllLines()

Comment: @HenkHolterman Very nice!  That's very handy.  Glad you pointed out that I didn't read your comment carefully enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to extract and parse a time of day:

```
    static TimeSpan? ExtractTime(string logLine)
    {
        var tokens = logLine.Split(new char [] { ' ', '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (tokens.Length < 2)
            return null;
        TimeSpan time;
        if (!TimeSpan.TryParse(tokens[1], out time))
            return null;
        return time;
    }

    static DateTime? ExtractDate(string logLine)
    {
        var tokens = logLine.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (tokens.Length < 1)
            return null;
        DateTime date;
        if (!DateTime.TryParse(tokens[0], out date))
            return null;
        return date;
    }

    static void OutputLogLinesBeforeTime(string strLogDirectory, string strLogDate, string strCallTime)
    {
        try
        {
            var time = TimeSpan.Parse(strCallTime);  // Throws a format exception if invalid.

            DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(strLogDirectory + "\\" + strLogDate + "\\");

            foreach (var file in d.GetFiles("*.ininlog_journal"))
            {
                try
                {
                    using (Stream stream = new FileStream(file.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                    using (StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        foreach (var line in sReader.EnumerateLines().Where(l => ExtractTime(l) < time))
                            Console.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ae)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ae.Message);
                }
                catch (SystemException se)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(se.Message);
                }
                catch (ApplicationException ape)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ape.Message);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ae)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ae.Message);
        }
        catch (SystemException se)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(se.Message);
        }
        catch (ApplicationException ape)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ape.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

For convenience I extracted the following:

```
public static class TextReaderExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(this TextReader sReader)
    {
        if (sReader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        string line;
        while ((line = sReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            yield return line;
    }
}
```

Comment: will give it a try and let you know

Comment: implemented the code you provided for some reason though no lines are getting outputted when looking at logline here is what I am seeing   logLine "2014/11/03 00:00:22\tPID:4332\tUUID:36515761-7ea8-4628-b137-2b4bed4ae7e5\tStart\tE:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/caasbillingserver.ininlog" string

Comment: @ondrovic - Your log file cells are delimited by both tabs and spaces; updated `ExtractTime` to split using either character.

Comment: That's working have one more item how hard would it be to alo compare against the date? Since our journal file has 2 dates in it

Comment: @ondrovic - I added code to show how you could parse the first cell in the log line into a [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Given two `DateTime` structs you can compare them using equality or inequality operators.

Comment: thanks for all the help still can't seem to get the date write, I tried doing the same thing as the extract time but can get it figured out

Comment: @ondrovic - you would need to show your code.  Bear in mind the `DateTime` structure contains both date and time information, to strip the time of day out you have to use [`.Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64335/discussion-between-ondrovic-and-dbc).