# Narrow Results of search

Tags: c#, string

Started the thread over here have successfully filter but need to narrow down

[Line Stream Reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745904/line-streamreader-readline-item)

I have log files that contain the following info

```
2014/11/03 00:00:00 PID:11484   UUID:231d09e2-56d9-43c1-8170-e45d43b56e4a   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip.ininlog
2014/11/03 06:02:11 PID:11484   UUID:231d09e2-56d9-43c1-8170-e45d43b56e4a   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip.ininlog
2014/11/03 06:02:11 PID:11484   UUID:fe49e587-6b40-446c-9b06-d16bae28683e   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_1.ininlog
2014/11/03 06:20:13 PID:11484   UUID:fe49e587-6b40-446c-9b06-d16bae28683e   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_1.ininlog
2014/11/03 06:20:13 PID:11484   UUID:3ec28198-f79e-4d36-90f9-5004ebe2ab91   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_2.ininlog
2014/11/03 06:35:29 PID:11484   UUID:3ec28198-f79e-4d36-90f9-5004ebe2ab91   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_2.ininlog
2014/11/03 06:35:29 PID:11484   UUID:ede8160a-d639-450c-8ccf-7f2c2a6c7823   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_3.ininlog
2014/11/03 06:49:41 PID:11484   UUID:ede8160a-d639-450c-8ccf-7f2c2a6c7823   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_3.ininlog
2014/11/03 06:49:41 PID:11484   UUID:c53a53e1-c81c-4d5b-8256-7d6ba2d886ff   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_4.ininlog
2014/11/03 07:03:20 PID:11484   UUID:c53a53e1-c81c-4d5b-8256-7d6ba2d886ff   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_4.ininlog
2014/11/03 07:03:20 PID:11484   UUID:be34b82a-a57f-4607-a638-b4f3dfca5617   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_5.ininlog
2014/11/03 07:16:15 PID:11484   UUID:be34b82a-a57f-4607-a638-b4f3dfca5617   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_5.ininlog
2014/11/03 07:16:15 PID:11484   UUID:7895acc1-29dc-4412-b1b8-34642d4a8752   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_6.ininlog
2014/11/03 07:28:07 PID:11484   UUID:7895acc1-29dc-4412-b1b8-34642d4a8752   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_6.ininlog
2014/11/03 07:28:07 PID:11484   UUID:72f09dc3-3e6e-44ce-a419-32679566bbb2   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_7.ininlog
2014/11/03 07:40:33 PID:11484   UUID:72f09dc3-3e6e-44ce-a419-32679566bbb2   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_7.ininlog
2014/11/03 07:40:33 PID:11484   UUID:29c1ec2e-7ab1-4d48-baf4-7b8ff8e2f04a   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_8.ininlog
2014/11/03 07:53:03 PID:11484   UUID:29c1ec2e-7ab1-4d48-baf4-7b8ff8e2f04a   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_8.ininlog
2014/11/03 07:53:03 PID:11484   UUID:aee440b6-05d5-426f-b7ba-cb17953d1331   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_9.ininlog
2014/11/03 08:04:20 PID:11484   UUID:aee440b6-05d5-426f-b7ba-cb17953d1331   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_9.ininlog
2014/11/03 08:04:20 PID:11484   UUID:b8bbcd9e-9033-4271-9b2e-e43a3c528772   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_10.ininlog
2014/11/03 08:15:09 PID:11484   UUID:b8bbcd9e-9033-4271-9b2e-e43a3c528772   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_10.ininlog
2014/11/03 08:15:09 PID:11484   UUID:fb8b70de-1725-47e0-9757-8a6ade8355a1   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_11.ininlog
2014/11/03 08:25:17 PID:11484   UUID:fb8b70de-1725-47e0-9757-8a6ade8355a1   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_11.ininlog
2014/11/03 08:25:17 PID:11484   UUID:0c5fec25-6b71-4240-8e7c-9333ecce9a3e   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_12.ininlog
2014/11/03 08:35:01 PID:11484   UUID:0c5fec25-6b71-4240-8e7c-9333ecce9a3e   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_12.ininlog
2014/11/03 08:35:01 PID:11484   UUID:68c1e9c9-1797-4b38-be41-d7675b847e0b   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_13.ininlog
2014/11/03 08:45:37 PID:11484   UUID:68c1e9c9-1797-4b38-be41-d7675b847e0b   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_13.ininlog
2014/11/03 08:45:37 PID:11484   UUID:883bf2bd-9731-4709-9c39-5b40f518a1d5   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_14.ininlog
2014/11/03 08:54:09 PID:11484   UUID:883bf2bd-9731-4709-9c39-5b40f518a1d5   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_14.ininlog
2014/11/03 08:54:09 PID:11484   UUID:9b925501-e0c0-469c-9336-59d742e80c6b   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_15.ininlog
2014/11/03 09:04:32 PID:11484   UUID:9b925501-e0c0-469c-9336-59d742e80c6b   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_15.ininlog
2014/11/03 09:04:32 PID:11484   UUID:a5e850d0-5989-4ad4-bd97-c47cdca444b7   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_16.ininlog
2014/11/03 09:15:00 PID:11484   UUID:a5e850d0-5989-4ad4-bd97-c47cdca444b7   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_16.ininlog
2014/11/03 09:15:00 PID:11484   UUID:fde960e3-1bda-469a-9c4d-fc1921d0e57e   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_17.ininlog
2014/11/03 09:25:28 PID:11484   UUID:fde960e3-1bda-469a-9c4d-fc1921d0e57e   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_17.ininlog
2014/11/03 09:25:28 PID:11484   UUID:eba5a083-13fa-42e3-a16b-c01a6ca0287f   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_18.ininlog
2014/11/03 09:35:57 PID:11484   UUID:eba5a083-13fa-42e3-a16b-c01a6ca0287f   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_18.ininlog
2014/11/03 09:35:57 PID:11484   UUID:51a5b17b-6b23-4087-a3e6-f1b001ae32b9   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_19.ininlog
2014/11/03 09:45:53 PID:11484   UUID:51a5b17b-6b23-4087-a3e6-f1b001ae32b9   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_19.ininlog
2014/11/03 09:45:53 PID:11484   UUID:6f0f7bd3-7081-4036-8864-905a118db2b9   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_20.ininlog
2014/11/03 09:55:52 PID:11484   UUID:6f0f7bd3-7081-4036-8864-905a118db2b9   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_20.ininlog
2014/11/03 09:55:52 PID:11484   UUID:83c5ad5f-b3b5-4167-b8e2-3a75b6162baf   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_21.ininlog
2014/11/03 10:04:50 PID:11484   UUID:83c5ad5f-b3b5-4167-b8e2-3a75b6162baf   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_21.ininlog
2014/11/03 10:04:50 PID:11484   UUID:58abf277-edb1-48ef-a0d1-ce9a2c53daca   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_22.ininlog
2014/11/03 10:13:46 PID:11484   UUID:58abf277-edb1-48ef-a0d1-ce9a2c53daca   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_22.ininlog
2014/11/03 10:13:46 PID:11484   UUID:6e9c61db-dd62-453b-bfa8-6d0e23fb428a   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_23.ininlog
2014/11/03 10:23:30 PID:11484   UUID:6e9c61db-dd62-453b-bfa8-6d0e23fb428a   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_23.ininlog
2014/11/03 10:23:30 PID:11484   UUID:16ea52aa-9f78-46b6-913b-308dbfe1ad4f   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_24.ininlog
2014/11/03 10:33:50 PID:11484   UUID:16ea52aa-9f78-46b6-913b-308dbfe1ad4f   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_24.ininlog
2014/11/03 10:33:50 PID:11484   UUID:8b7b310c-657a-4665-842e-7fcb40dc8df1   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_25.ininlog
2014/11/03 10:43:55 PID:11484   UUID:8b7b310c-657a-4665-842e-7fcb40dc8df1   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_25.ininlog
2014/11/03 10:43:55 PID:11484   UUID:4e707790-18ff-4ba8-93d5-d198e978f63f   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_26.ininlog
2014/11/03 10:54:10 PID:11484   UUID:4e707790-18ff-4ba8-93d5-d198e978f63f   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_26.ininlog
2014/11/03 10:54:10 PID:11484   UUID:176c4bca-84fb-4361-9898-f500edc348bb   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_27.ininlog
2014/11/03 11:05:09 PID:11484   UUID:176c4bca-84fb-4361-9898-f500edc348bb   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_27.ininlog
2014/11/03 11:05:09 PID:11484   UUID:70afef6a-fcd3-4fac-aaf6-6c419b2bfbba   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_28.ininlog
2014/11/03 11:14:38 PID:11484   UUID:70afef6a-fcd3-4fac-aaf6-6c419b2bfbba   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_28.ininlog
2014/11/03 11:14:38 PID:11484   UUID:09c4b5ec-c88a-4687-a0c5-84b6bbd402cd   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_29.ininlog
2014/11/03 11:24:06 PID:11484   UUID:09c4b5ec-c88a-4687-a0c5-84b6bbd402cd   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_29.ininlog
2014/11/03 11:24:06 PID:11484   UUID:bca881be-4310-447e-89d1-21af0d1c528a   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_30.ininlog
2014/11/03 11:34:22 PID:11484   UUID:bca881be-4310-447e-89d1-21af0d1c528a   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_30.ininlog
2014/11/03 11:34:22 PID:11484   UUID:424c6ca2-6ede-468a-868a-4372c4b0556c   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_31.ininlog
2014/11/03 11:45:01 PID:11484   UUID:424c6ca2-6ede-468a-868a-4372c4b0556c   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_31.ininlog
2014/11/03 11:45:01 PID:11484   UUID:b5458703-74e4-41d9-ab21-2cbc8576389f   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_32.ininlog
2014/11/03 11:56:15 PID:11484   UUID:b5458703-74e4-41d9-ab21-2cbc8576389f   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_32.ininlog
2014/11/03 11:56:15 PID:11484   UUID:337458a2-85a2-47c7-a101-73ac489ed3bf   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_33.ininlog
2014/11/03 12:06:44 PID:11484   UUID:337458a2-85a2-47c7-a101-73ac489ed3bf   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_33.ininlog
2014/11/03 12:06:44 PID:11484   UUID:8a1aef00-f1e3-4060-b24c-35ef77e905bf   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_34.ininlog
2014/11/03 12:17:26 PID:11484   UUID:8a1aef00-f1e3-4060-b24c-35ef77e905bf   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_34.ininlog
2014/11/03 12:17:26 PID:11484   UUID:dde16219-46bb-4d6a-8387-ef05886cb828   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_35.ininlog
2014/11/03 12:28:30 PID:11484   UUID:dde16219-46bb-4d6a-8387-ef05886cb828   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_35.ininlog
2014/11/03 12:28:30 PID:11484   UUID:82c1e793-a963-4e56-ab00-ccb75b90e68c   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_36.ininlog
2014/11/03 12:39:35 PID:11484   UUID:82c1e793-a963-4e56-ab00-ccb75b90e68c   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_36.ininlog
2014/11/03 12:39:35 PID:11484   UUID:2adce285-9689-43b1-835a-a7402a4e8f89   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_37.ininlog
2014/11/03 12:51:09 PID:11484   UUID:2adce285-9689-43b1-835a-a7402a4e8f89   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_37.ininlog
2014/11/03 12:51:09 PID:11484   UUID:7ea39118-a311-44b2-a895-7388dfaeb1fd   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_38.ininlog
2014/11/03 13:03:19 PID:11484   UUID:7ea39118-a311-44b2-a895-7388dfaeb1fd   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_38.ininlog
2014/11/03 13:03:19 PID:11484   UUID:7be575bb-4322-4416-b1ae-f464938cf6ce   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_39.ininlog
2014/11/03 13:15:30 PID:11484   UUID:7be575bb-4322-4416-b1ae-f464938cf6ce   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_39.ininlog
2014/11/03 13:15:30 PID:11484   UUID:6799a8a8-de76-4832-8fad-a829354c8a4a   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_40.ininlog
2014/11/03 13:27:41 PID:11484   UUID:6799a8a8-de76-4832-8fad-a829354c8a4a   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_40.ininlog
2014/11/03 13:27:41 PID:11484   UUID:f0945238-5ed6-4e1f-9990-8f61ad81bc15   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_41.ininlog
2014/11/03 13:39:56 PID:11484   UUID:f0945238-5ed6-4e1f-9990-8f61ad81bc15   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_41.ininlog
2014/11/03 13:39:56 PID:11484   UUID:02eef369-6d38-4d28-b2e1-666adebea9a3   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_42.ininlog
2014/11/03 13:53:05 PID:11484   UUID:02eef369-6d38-4d28-b2e1-666adebea9a3   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_42.ininlog
2014/11/03 13:53:05 PID:11484   UUID:3a1df262-d892-4ede-8152-07403c5b1ae1   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_43.ininlog
2014/11/03 14:06:32 PID:11484   UUID:3a1df262-d892-4ede-8152-07403c5b1ae1   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_43.ininlog
2014/11/03 14:06:32 PID:11484   UUID:59aa8395-d6fd-4210-8b3f-8008a057d2d5   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_44.ininlog
2014/11/03 14:21:19 PID:11484   UUID:59aa8395-d6fd-4210-8b3f-8008a057d2d5   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_44.ininlog
2014/11/03 14:21:19 PID:11484   UUID:ee0b747a-dfe7-4c6f-825a-93c446da8aab   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_45.ininlog
2014/11/03 14:37:13 PID:11484   UUID:ee0b747a-dfe7-4c6f-825a-93c446da8aab   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_45.ininlog
2014/11/03 14:37:13 PID:11484   UUID:f834b1c0-a875-49e7-9bef-cae5be12f424   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_46.ininlog
2014/11/03 14:53:46 PID:11484   UUID:f834b1c0-a875-49e7-9bef-cae5be12f424   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_46.ininlog
2014/11/03 14:53:46 PID:11484   UUID:21ac9763-7d47-48d5-8d1e-4568d2105bc5   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_47.ininlog
2014/11/03 15:10:30 PID:11484   UUID:21ac9763-7d47-48d5-8d1e-4568d2105bc5   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_47.ininlog
2014/11/03 15:10:30 PID:11484   UUID:77f146b0-fc5a-4b41-9795-4cf733b8f254   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_48.ininlog
2014/11/03 15:30:23 PID:11484   UUID:77f146b0-fc5a-4b41-9795-4cf733b8f254   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_48.ininlog
2014/11/03 15:30:23 PID:11484   UUID:bf1d62ab-4a66-4b44-bc91-2b27d26cde81   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_49.ininlog
2014/11/03 15:54:12 PID:11484   UUID:bf1d62ab-4a66-4b44-bc91-2b27d26cde81   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_49.ininlog
2014/11/03 15:54:12 PID:11484   UUID:b0bbf12a-0d5f-43e0-ba3c-f18bcd04c7d7   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_50.ininlog
2014/11/03 16:19:26 PID:11484   UUID:b0bbf12a-0d5f-43e0-ba3c-f18bcd04c7d7   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_50.ininlog
2014/11/03 16:19:26 PID:11484   UUID:8547bbbc-2c92-4878-a408-f62161e7a273   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_51.ininlog
2014/11/03 16:50:35 PID:11484   UUID:8547bbbc-2c92-4878-a408-f62161e7a273   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_51.ininlog
2014/11/03 16:50:35 PID:11484   UUID:bba969c0-a2c9-423d-8ec6-a999cb5ca3b2   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_52.ininlog
2014/11/03 17:52:50 PID:11484   UUID:bba969c0-a2c9-423d-8ec6-a999cb5ca3b2   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_52.ininlog
2014/11/03 17:52:50 PID:11484   UUID:aa5a2037-b42e-42af-aa9e-61e040d408c5   Start   E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_53.ininlog
2014/11/04 00:00:00 PID:11484   UUID:aa5a2037-b42e-42af-aa9e-61e040d408c5   End E:/I3/IC/Logs/2014-11-03/ip_53.ininlog
```

If look for an item that has a time of 23:00:00 it returns all logs up to that point, which is not what I need. I only need the last log that would fall in that time range so if I used 23:00:00 as a time when it hits the ip journal file it should only tell me that I need ip_53 log not all 53 logs.

I am using the following code to accomplish my search so far

```
static TimeSpan? ExtractTime(string logLine)
{
  var tokens = logLine.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
  if (tokens.Length < 2)
    return null;
  TimeSpan time;
  if (!TimeSpan.TryParse(tokens[1], out time))
    return null;
  return time; 
}

static DateTime? ExtractDate(string logLine)
{
  var tokens = logLine.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
  if (tokens.Length < 1)
    return null;
  DateTime date;
  if (!DateTime.TryParse(tokens[0], out date))
    return null;
  return date;
}

static void OutputLogLinesBeforeTime(string LogDir, string LogDate, string LogTime)
{
  try
  {
    var time = TimeSpan.Parse(LogTime);
    var date = DateTime.Parse(LogDate).Date;
    DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(LogDir + "\\" + LogDate + "\\");
    foreach (var file in d.GetFiles("*.ininlog_journal"))
    {
      try
      {
        using (Stream stream = new FileStream(file.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        using (StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
          foreach (var line in sReader.EnumerateLines().Where(l => ExtractTime(l) <= time && ExtractDate(l) == date))
            callLogs.Add(line);           
         }
       }
       catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ae)
       {
         Console.WriteLine(ae.Message);
       }
       catch (SystemException se)
       {
         Console.WriteLine(se.Message);
       }
       catch (ApplicationException ape)
       {
         Console.WriteLine(ape.Message);
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
         Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
       }
     }
     foreach (var e in callLogs)
       Console.WriteLine(e);
   }
   catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ae)
   {
     Console.WriteLine(ae.Message);
   }
   catch (SystemException se)
   {
     Console.WriteLine(se.Message);
   }
   catch (ApplicationException ape)
   {
     Console.WriteLine(ape.Message);
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
     Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
foreach (var line in sReader.EnumerateLines().Where(l => ExtractTime(l) <= time && ExtractDate(l) == date))
        callLogs.Add(line);
```

Is iterating each row in the file and storing *any* row that matches the row you are after. If you are only interested in the *last* row that matches your criteria you could either access the last item of `callLogs` using the Linq [LastOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.lastordefault%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) method:

```
Console.WriteLine(callLogs.LastOrDefault());
```

Or you could grab the last item directly without storing anything inbetween:

```
string justOneRow = sReader.EnumerateLines().LastOrDefault(l => ExtractTime(l) <= time && ExtractDate(l) == date);
Console.WriteLine(justOneRow);
```

Note that the `Where` you were using previously has changed to `LastOrDefault`.

This assumes that the log files are in date order. If they're not you would have to order the list before taking the last item. In that case I would create an anonymous object so you aren't calling `ExtractDate` and `ExtractTime` more than you need to:

```
string justOneRow = sReader.EnumerateLines().Select(l => new 
{
    Date = ExtractDate(l),
    Time = ExtractTime(l),
    RowText = l
}).Where(l => l.Time <= time && l.Date == date)
.OrderBy(l => l.Date).ThenBy(l => l.Time).LastOrDefault().RowText;
```